# BufferedReader to Jsonarray in android

Tags: java, android, json, file, bufferedreader

I have a jsonFile in this format.

```
 [{"KeyTokenName":"Safe 2","UntilTime":"16:39","FromTime":"16:39","FromDate":"2015\/04\/10","Count":8,"KeyRingId":1,"UntilDate":"2016\/04\/10"}]
 [{"KeyTokenName":"Safe 1","UntilTime":"16:40","FromTime":"16:40","FromDate":"2015\/04\/10","Count":15,"KeyRingId":1,"UntilDate":"2016\/04\/10"}]
 [{"KeyTokenName":"Safe 1","UntilTime":"16:42","FromTime":"16:42","FromDate":"2015\/04\/10","Count":25,"KeyRingId":1,"UntilDate":"2016\/04\/10"}]
```

I am trying to read from the json file using this code.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while (bis.available() != 0) {
    char c = (char) bis.read();
    b.append(c);
    }

bis.close();
inputStream.close();

JSONArray data = new JSONArray(b.toString());
```

But I In data object I only get the content of the first object from the json file that is

```
[{"KeyTokenName":"Safe 2","FromDate":"2015\/04\/10","FromTime":"16:39","UntilTime":"16:39","Count":8,"UntilDate":"2016\/04\/10","KeyRingId":1}]
```

But I want all the content to be in there is the Json array object. What needs to be done. I don't want to use any external libraries for Json parsing.

Please help.

Comment: How do you expect a single `JSONArray` object to store 3 JSON arrays?

Comment: if you are sure that the file contains a list of arrays and you want to read it as a list of array, probably you can simply append a "[]" before and after the contain, then parse it to JSONArray.

Comment: Yes.The file contains a list of arrays. Can you please explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use some existing solutions that allow you to do mapping of java class to json and vice versa like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library?